# VSMSDeploy task fails with a timeout

Tags: visual-studio, timeout, web-deployment, msdeploy

When trying a web deploy from inside visual studio 2015 I get this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL '<mydomain>'.)

Could not complete the request to remote agent URL '<mydomain>'.
The operation has timed out App C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    4283
```

This happens after I Have successfully validated the connection using the Visual Studio UI.

I also successfully published to the local file system.

It happens a a relatively  fast connection (1MB per second upload).

It happens on multiply connections (different ISPs).

This happens after I deployed many times successful using the same method during the last year.

I **does not happen** when creating a new minimal web app and deploying it.

Comment: Try running as admin. Make sure you have all VS updates. Do you get the error when you run msdeploy.exe directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out the reason, was very mad when I did.

I have changed the verbosity of the build process to diagnostic while working on a different project.

When deploying with this setting the output the the build console when slowing down the deployment, and then the deployment timed-out, but only when working on a big project that is moving a lot of files as part of the build.

Setting the verbosity back to normal fixed it.

This is of course not a good thing, as one of the steps to take when you have a deployment problem is to increase verbosity to try to find the problem.But now I know that doing that will only add one more problem :(

This seems to be a general problem with VS where printing out output can significantly slowdown the system, including in unit tests.

Comment: Exact same symptoms and solution.  Very poor indeed.

Comment: Same here, very annoying. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: omg...took me 2 days to find this, tried whitelisting, changing http to https, restarting vs etc and this is the solution...frustrating indeed.

Comment: I have this exact behavior from TeamCity build-server running msdeploy.exe on an ASP.NET-site.